# Nesting an AJAX call in a for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, dom, for-loop

I'm attempting to perform an AJAX call and iterate the url parameter for every entry in an array. As such:

```
arr = ['images', 'videos', 'pictures'];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    $.ajax({
        url: arr[i],
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
}
```

For reasons that escape me it simply doesn't work. Nesting the AJAX call in the for loop appears to just perform the code once and never iterate it.

Comment: Why do you believe that to be the case?

Comment: It should work as you've written it.

Comment: @Barmar unless (perhaps) he is trying to reference `i` in the callback?

Comment: @Alnitak Right, but I'm just going by what he's written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *should* work OK, unless you're trying to reference `i` in the unshown callback function, since `i` there will refer to the final value from the loop, not the current value.

If that's the case, then instead try this:

```
var arr = ['images', 'videos', 'pictures'];
arr.forEach(function(url, i) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function() {
             // i may now be used safely here
        }
    });
});
```

NB: these days, I'd use `.done` or `.then` rather than `success:`.